# Remove area between x axis and x ticks

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I would like to remove the space between the x axis and the x ticks. It would be the area in the red rectangle. 
Eg.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
```

I came across with loads of info on x label spacing but not on the distance between the x labels and the x axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` to your `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image: Boxplot with removed area between x-axis and plot-area]